# How to obtain the semipartial r squared (sr2) for simple slopes (lows/highs) in regression?

Tags: r, regression, interaction

## Note:

I'm reposting a modified version of this post from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224682/how-to-obtain-the-semipartial-r-squared-sr2-for-simple-slopes-lows-highs-in) because I didn't receive any response there and I'm thinking that it might be because I'm asking a question about the statistical validity of a particular procedure, in which case I think it might be more appropriate here(?). (Perhaps someone could comment to advise whether I should delete the post on Stackoverflow)

## Question

I know how to obtain the semipartial *r* squared (*sr*2) of a three-way interaction term in a regression:

```
require(lmSupport)
require(interactions)
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ am * disp * vs, data = mtcars)
summary(mod1)
interact_plot(mod1,pred=am,modx=disp,mod2=vs) # just to visualise it
modelEffectSizes(mod1)

                     SSR df pEta-sqr dR-sqr
(Intercept) 215.5504  1   0.6040     NA
am            6.9959  1   0.0472 0.0062
disp         24.2622  1   0.1465 0.0215
vs            0.4509  1   0.0032 0.0004
am:disp       6.6017  1   0.0446 0.0059
am:vs        39.8954  1   0.2201 0.0354
disp:vs       0.0865  1   0.0006 0.0001
am:disp:vs   61.5751  1   0.3035 0.0547 # This one

pEta-sqr = partial eta squared
dR-sqr = delta R2 (sr2)
```

In R, [the *SR*2 is given as the delta R-square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224682/how-to-obtain-the-semipartial-r-squared-sr2-for-simple-slopes-lows-highs-in), represented by the last column above.

I know how to obtain the simple slopes of the model.

```
(ss <- sim_slopes(mod1, pred = am, modx = disp, mod2 = vs))
plot(ss)
```

However, I'm being asked to provide the *sr*2 for the individual simple slopes (lows, -1 SD, and highs, +1 SD)... Someone gave me a trick to do it, but I don't know enough statistics to see if it's a valid/the recommended procedure. Basically, to get the scores for lows/highs, he adds/subtracts the standard deviation to the moderator, before computing the model again.

```
# Low (-1 SD) disp ("lows")
mtcars$disp_L <- mtcars$disp + sd(mtcars$disp)
mod1_L <- lm(mpg ~ am * disp_L * vs, data = mtcars)
summary(mod1_L)
modelEffectSizes(mod1_L)

                  SSR df pEta-sqr dR-sqr
(Intercept)  149.9703  1   0.5148     NA
am             7.0893  1   0.0478 0.0063 # this one?
disp_L        24.2622  1   0.1465 0.0215
vs             0.1155  1   0.0008 0.0001
am:disp_L      6.6017  1   0.0446 0.0059
am:vs         53.3319  1   0.2740 0.0474 # or this one?
disp_L:vs      0.0865  1   0.0006 0.0001
am:disp_L:vs  61.5751  1   0.3035 0.0547

# Highs (+1 SD) disp ("highs")
mtcars$disp_H <- mtcars$disp - sd(mtcars$disp)
mod1_H <- lm(mpg ~ am * disp_H * vs, data = mtcars)
summary(mod1_H)
modelEffectSizes(mod1_H)

                  SSR df pEta-sqr dR-sqr
(Intercept)  378.0400  1   0.7279     NA
am             6.1808  1   0.0419 0.0055 # this one?
disp_H        24.2622  1   0.1465 0.0215
vs             2.3113  1   0.0161 0.0021
am:disp_H      6.6017  1   0.0446 0.0059
am:vs          6.0988  1   0.0414 0.0054 # or this one?
disp_H:vs      0.0865  1   0.0006 0.0001
am:disp_H:vs  61.5751  1   0.3035 0.0547
```

My understanding is that the correct slope to report is the new *sr*2 for the predictor "am" (rather than the one from the interaction term), but to be honest the three-way interaction is confusing me.

Now the other problem is that this procedure only gives one *sr*2 of interest, whereas we should get one for when vs = 0, and another when vs = 1. I suspected that this might be due to vs = 0 being the reference condition, so I tried reverse-coding the dummy-codes, but I'm still a little lost as to the correct interpretation.

Is that the correct way to proceed? Is there a package/command that can do it for me? I couldn't find any documentation on this. Any resource you can point me to? Thanks for any help!